# Delete unfinished downloaded file if download gets cancelled

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I'm downloading file with AFNetworking, using this code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadFileUrl]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString * targetFileName = [downloadFileUrl lastPathComponent];
NSString * targetPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:targetFileName];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:targetPath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadDidSuccessNotification" object:nil];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadDidFailedNotification" object:nil];

}];

[operation start];
```

I provide the option to user to cancel the download, I do that by this:

```
[operation cancel];
```

However, the unfinished downloaded file remains in the directory.
Please let me know the solution to delete the unfinished downloaded file.

Comment: While you are cancelling download operation or download operation failed, there you can get the path of file and delete it from directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. I didn't check.

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadDidSuccessNotification" object:nil];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
      NSError *error = nil;
     BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:targetPath error:&error];
        if (!removeSuccess) {
            // Error handling
            ...
        }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadDidFailedNotification" object:nil];

}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to delete file -

```
NSArray *searchPaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL success=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: targetPath];
 if (success)
 {
      BOOL deletedFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: targetPath error:&error];
     if (deletedFile)
        NSLog(@"File deleted");
     else
        NSLog(@"Not able to delete File");
}
```